# How to read this length interval in imperial units?

Tags: units, length

I am from Europe and I do some research for my thesis. I found this picture, which is very usefull for me, but unfortunately the lengths are in imperial units (for lenght they are using something like this 7'-11.5''). I know, that this symbol: ' is for feet and this: '' is for inches. 
But I am little bit struggling with this notation. Is this interval (it doesn't make much sense if so) or it's x feets minus y inches?

Thanks for the answers, I know that this is lame question, but as European metric system user I am little bit confused :)

[image]

Comment: I read `7'-2.5"` as *seven feet and two-and-a-half inches*.

Comment: The "-" stands for "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the dashes.  They *should* just be written as 7'11.5", etc., as seen in [this standard reference](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0007.html).  But some times people like to put dashes just because they think it looks ugly without them.  [Here's one example](http://communities.bentley.com/products/microstation/f/273/t/106533) of someone explicitly saying he wants to do it the way seen here, mentioning that it's what "you would see on a set of plans here in America".  (As an American, I would say that I see it without a dash more often, but I have seen it both ways.  And I agree that with the dash is confusing -- and distracting.)

Comment: (+1) actually, they *should* be written as $2.43\ \mathrm m$ ;-)

Comment: And, of course, there are 2.54 cm/inch, and 12 inches/foot.  Also, 1 m is equal to 39.37 inches.  Hopefully, all of the comments answered the question adequately.